# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page on which i have one grid(maingrid) and one usercontrol which contains a grid.
When i select a ros in the maingrid i show some information in the usercontrols grid.
Now, when i am binding the usercontrol grid with some list it's showing me the 
error `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected`.
I don't know what it is, any idea on this would be appreciated.
The code of the control is as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="CompanyDetails.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="BasWare.SupplierPortal.CWA.UI.UserControls.CompanyDetails" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/DataListControl.ascx" TagName="DataListCtrl" TagPrefix="uc2" %>

<div id="divMain" runat="server"> 
    <table class="panelContentTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
      <tr>
            <td widht="80">
                <table border="0" width="100%">                
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel ID="lblOrganizationID" runat="server" Text="Company number:"
                                    meta:resourcekey="lblOrganizationID" RequiredIndicationLabelText="* "></bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel>
                                <br />
                                <div id="divOrganizationIDEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtOrganizationID" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" ControlContext="Supplier"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtOrganizationID" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                    <bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValCompanyNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessageIconURL="~/images/error-message.gif"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtOrganizationID" meta:resourcekey="reqValCompanyNumber"></bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divOrganizationIDReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtOrganizationIDRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly"
                                        ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel ID="lblCompanyName" runat="server" Text="Company Name:"
                                    meta:resourcekey="lblCompanyName" RequiredIndicationLabelText="* "></bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel>
                                <br />
                                <div id="divCompanyNameEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" RequiredPermission="EditCompanyProfile"
                                        ControlContext="Invoice" meta:resourcekey="txtCompanyName"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                    <bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValCompanyName" runat="server" ErrorMessageIconURL="~/images/error-message.gif"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtCompanyName" meta:resourcekey="reqValCompanyName"></bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCompanyNameReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyNameRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Email:" RequiredIndicationLabelText="* "
                                    meta:resourcekey="Label1"></bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel>
                                <br />
                                <div id="divEmailEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" ControlContext="Users"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtEmail" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                    <bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessageIconURL="~/images/error-message.gif"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtEmail" meta:resourcekey="reqValEmail"></bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divEmailReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtEmailRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <bw:BWRequiredFieldLabel ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Country:" meta:resourcekey="Label10" RequiredIndicationLabelText="* " /><br />
                                <div id="divCountryEdit" runat="server">
                                    <uc2:DataListCtrl ID="dlCountry" runat="server" DefaultList="DefaultCountryCodes" ShowEmptyValue="true" />
                                    <bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValCountryCode" runat="server" ErrorMessageIconURL="~/images/error-message.gif"
                                        ControlToValidate="dlCountry" meta:resourcekey="reqValCountryCode"></bw:BWRequiredFieldValidator>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCountryReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCountryRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyVATNumber" runat="server" Text="VAT number:" meta:resourcekey="lblCompanyVATNumber"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divCompanyVATNumberEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyVATNumber" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtCompanyVATNumber" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCompanyVATNumberReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyVATNumberRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyRCSNumber" runat="server" Text="RCS number:" meta:resourcekey="lblCompanyRCSNumber"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divCompanyRCSNumberEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyRCSNumber" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtCompanyVATNumber" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCompanyRCSNumberReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyRCSNumberRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Street:" meta:resourcekey="Label3"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divStreetEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtStreet" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        SkipValidation="True" meta:resourcekey="txtStreet" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divStreetReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtStreetRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Postal code:" meta:resourcekey="Label4"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divPostalCodeEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        SkipValidation="True" meta:resourcekey="txtPostalCode" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divPostalCodeReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtPostalCodeRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="City:" meta:resourcekey="Label5"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divCityEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        SkipValidation="True" meta:resourcekey="txtCity" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCityReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCityRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                               <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyState" runat="server" Text="State / province:" meta:resourcekey="lblCompanyState" ></asp:Label><br />
                               <div id="divCompanyState" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyState" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"
                                       SkipValidation="true" meta:resourcekey="txtState" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile" ></bw:BWTextBox>
                               </div>
                               <div id="divCompanyStateReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyStateRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone number:" meta:resourcekey="lblCompanyPhone"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divCompanyPhoneEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyPhone" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" ControlContext="Supplier"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtCompanyPhone" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCompanyPhoneReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanyPhoneRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCompanySite" runat="server" Text="Country:" meta:resourcekey="lblCompanySite"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divCompanySiteEdit" runat="server">
                                     <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanySite" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        SkipValidation="True" meta:resourcekey="txtCompanySite" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divCompanySiteReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtCompanySiteRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbleInvoicingAddress" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lbleInvoicingAddress"
                                    Text="eInvoicing address:"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divEInvoiceEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txteInvoicingAddress" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        SkipValidation="True" meta:resourcekey="txteInvoicingAddress" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divEInvoiceReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txteInvoicingAddressRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly"
                                        ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <div id="divFaxNumber" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFaxNumber" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblFaxNumber" Text="Fax number:"></asp:Label><br />
                                    <div id="divFaxNumberEdit" runat="server">
                                        <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtFaxNumber" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                            meta:resourcekey="txtFaxNumber" SkipValidation="True" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="divFaxNumberReadOnly" runat="server">
                                        <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtFaxNumberRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="parentCompanyControl" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblParentCustomer" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblParentCustomer"
                                        Text="Parent customer:"></asp:Label><br />
                                    <bw:BWParentOrganizationPicker ID="organizationPicker" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="supplierBankDetaisRow" runat="server">
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblBankName" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblBankName" Text="Bank name:"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divBankEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtBankName" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtBankName" SkipValidation="True" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divBankReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtBankNameRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblBankAccount" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblBankAccount" Text="Bank account:"></asp:Label><br />
                                <div id="divBankAccountEdit" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtBankAccount" runat="server" ControlContext="Users" CssClass="TextBox"
                                        meta:resourcekey="txtBankAccount" SkipValidation="True" RequiredPermission="ViewProfile"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divBankAccountReadOnly" runat="server">
                                    <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtBankAccountRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                                 <div id="divLanguage" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLanguage" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblLanguage" Text="Select language:"></asp:Label><br />
                                    <div id="divLanguageEdit" runat="server">
                                        <bw:BWDropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" ControlContext="Invoice" CssClass="dropDownList"
                                            meta:resourcekey="ddlLanguage" Width="157px">
                                        </bw:BWDropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="divLanguageReadOnly" runat="server">
                                        <bw:BWTextBox ID="txtLanguageRO" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxReadOnly" ReadOnly="true"></bw:BWTextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="firstTD">
                               <div id="divAutoApprove" runat="server">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAutoApprove" runat="server" Text="Allow auto-approving" Checked="false"
                                        CausesValidation="false" Enabled="true" meta:resourcekey="chkAutoApprove" />
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td class="middleTD">

                            </td>
                            <td class="lastTD" style="height: 24px">
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                            <bw:BWGridViewDynamic ID="showBankAccountGrid" CssClass="DGTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                RowSelectingEnabled="True" RowStyle-CssClass="DGItem" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="DGSelectedItem" DataKeyNames="BankAccountID,IsDefault"
                                FooterStyle-CssClass="DGFooterTR" EditRowStyle-CssClass="DGEditItemValidator" Visible="false">
                                <Columns>
                                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bank name / SWIFT:" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" meta:resourcekey="bankNameHeaderText">                                                                                                         
                                           <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblBankName" Text='<%# Eval("BankName") %>' runat="server" Visible="true" >                                                                                                               
                                                </asp:Label>                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                            </ItemTemplate>  
                                            <EditItemTemplate >
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="bankNameTextBox" runat="server" />
                                            </EditItemTemplate>                                                                         
                                       </asp:TemplateField>  
                                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bank account / IBAN:" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" meta:resourcekey="bankACNHeaderText">                                                                                                         
                                           <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblBankAccount" Text='<%# Eval("BankAccountNumber") %>' runat="server" Visible="true" >                                                                                                               
                                                </asp:Label>                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                            </ItemTemplate>                                                                           
                                            <EditItemTemplate >
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankAccountNumber" runat="server" />
                                            </EditItemTemplate>                                                                         
                                       </asp:TemplateField>   
                                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  meta:resourcekey="IsDefaultHeaderText">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsDefault" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsDefault_CheckedChanged"> 
                                             </asp:CheckBox>
                                         </ItemTemplate>
                                       </asp:TemplateField>  
                                </Columns>
                                 <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="DGSelectedItem" />                  
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="DGHeaderTR" />       
                            </bw:BWGridViewDynamic>
                            </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:Panel ID="supplierDetailsPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <div class="panelTitle"><asp:Label ID="lblBankAccounts" runat="server" Text="Bank Accounts:" meta:resourcekey="lblBankAccounts"></asp:Label></div>
                <div class="SubToolbarBorderless">                
                         <bw:BWButton ID="btnAddBankAccount" runat="server" ButtonCSSClass="newbutton" ButtonCSSClassDisabled="newbuttonDisabled"
                            ToolTip="Add New" SeparatorCSSClass="separator" SeparatorImageURL="~/images/toolbar-separator.gif"
                            RequiredActionPermission="None" CommandName="" ConfirmationMessage="" LabelCSSClass=""
                            LabelText="Add New" CausesValidation="false" meta:resourcekey="btnAddBankAccount" OnClick="btnAddBankAccount_OnClick" />                            

                        <bw:BWButton ID="btnEditBankAccount" runat="server" ButtonCSSClass="editbutton" ButtonCSSClassDisabled="editbuttonDisabled"
                            ToolTip="Edit Bank Details" SeparatorCSSClass="separator" SeparatorImageURL="~/images/toolbar-separator.gif"
                            RequiredActionPermission="None" CommandName="" ConfirmationMessage="" 
                            LabelCSSClass="" LabelText="Edit"  meta:resourcekey="btnEditBankAccount"
                            CausesValidation="false"  OnClick="btnEditBankAccount_Click"/>

                        <bw:BWButton ID="btnDeleteBankAccount" runat="server" ButtonCSSClass="deletebutton"
                            ButtonCSSClassDisabled="deletebuttonDisabled" ToolTip="Delete selected bank account(s)"
                            SeparatorCSSClass="separator" SeparatorImageURL="~/images/toolbar-separator.gif"
                            RequiredActionPermission="None" ConfirmationMessage="" OnClientClick="" LabelCSSClass=""
                             LabelText="Delete" meta:resourcekey="btnDeleteBankAccount" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnDeleteBankAccount_OnClick" />      

                        <bw:BWButton ID="btnSaveBankAccount" runat="server" Visible="false" ButtonCSSClass="updatebutton"
                             ToolTip="Update bank account" SeparatorCSSClass="separator" SeparatorImageURL="~/images/toolbar-separator.gif"
                             RequiredActionPermission="None" CommandName="" ConfirmationMessage="" OnClientClick="" OnClick="btnSaveBankAccount_Click" LabelText="Save"
                             meta:resourcekey="btnSaveBankAccount" CausesValidation="false" />                

                       <bw:BWButton ID="btnCancelBankAccountEdit" runat="server" ButtonCSSClass="cancelbutton" 
                             ButtonCSSClassDisabled="cancelbuttonDisabled" ToolTip="Cancel bank account  editing" SeparatorCSSClass="separator"
                             SeparatorImageURL="~/images/toolbar-separator.gif" RequiredActionPermission="None" Visible="false" 
                             CommandName="" ConfirmationMessage="" OnClientClick="" LabelCSSClass="" LabelText="Cancel"
                             meta:resourcekey="btnCancelBankAccountEdit" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnCancelEdit_Click" /> 
                 </div>
                 <bw:BWGridViewDynamic ID="grdBankAccounts" CssClass="DGTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    RowSelectingEnabled="True" RowStyle-CssClass="DGItem" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="DGSelectedItem" DataKeyNames="BankAccountID,IsDefault"
                    FooterStyle-CssClass="DGFooterTR" EditRowStyle-CssClass="DGEditItemValidator" 
                    OnRowCreated ="grdBankAccounts_GridViewRowCreated" >
                    <Columns>  
                         <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="CustomerStatusHeader">
                         <headertemplate>
                            <bw:BWButton id="btnSelectAll" runat="server" OnClick="btnSelectAll_Click" meta:resourcekey="btnSelectAll" ButtonCSSClass="selectAllButton" ButtonCSSClassDisabled="selectAllButtonDisabled"></bw:BWButton>
                            <bw:BWButton id="btnUnselectAll" runat="server" OnClick="btnUnselectAll_Click" meta:resourc
```